# Как в Contact Form 7 сделать отправку одной формы для одного пользователя?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Как в Contact Form 7 сделать отправку одной формы для одного пользователя:

Форм может быть много, но отправить каждую форму пользователь может только один раз, как это можно реализовать? Нигде не могу найти данную информацию

Comment: например можно после отправки формы первый раз создать куки и потом при наличии куки прятать форму либо вообще ее не выводить

Comment: Допустим, но как это реализовать если пользователь например зайдет с другого айпи адреса или с другого браузера, ведь куки сбросятся.

Comment: если форму могут заполнять все пользователи то нет смысла хранить эту информацию в базе, потому что вы никак не сможете проверить то что пользователь зашел под другим ip и т.д. с авторизированными пользователями все проще)

Comment: За сколько вы сможете решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Просто самостоятельно решить не смогу, необходима помощь